# Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405 on Angular Js1 and Webapi 2

Tags: angularjs, cors, asp.net-web-api2, angular-resource, preflight

Error:

```
OPTIONS http://localhost:8080//api/home/GetText 405 (Method Not Allowed)

http://localhost:8080//api/home/GetText. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405
angular.js:14362 Error: Error getting home/GetText data from the database! 
Headers:
```

Response Headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:false
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:gid,Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Allow:GET
Content-Length:76
Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
Date:Fri, 28 Jul 2017 10:30:06 GMT
Server:Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
```

Request Headers:

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Access-Control-Request-Headers:authorization,gid
Access-Control-Request-Method:GET
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Host:localhost:8080
Origin:http://evil.com/
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:http://localhost:1852/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36
```

Please note that i am using Angular Js as client and Webapi for server side. I am performing xhr request through $resource service.

Answer (score 1):

This is because your back-end API doesn't support `OPTIONS` request for your routes (specifically `/api/home/GetText` this route). AngularJS typically checks CORS requests by issuing `OPTIONS` requests prior to making actual content requests.

You need to enable support for `OPTIONS` requests at your back-end, and return appropriate headers + good HTTP status (200-299) from there.

Comment: I added code for the same. now i am not able to read the headers.

Comment: i want to read the header 'X-filename:Letter.pdf'. getting in the response while opening the request in developer mode but in js file i am not getting it. In IE it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
 protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod != "OPTIONS") return;
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "gid, filename, Origin, X - Requested - With, Content - Type, Accept, Authorization");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "X-filename");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
        }
```

This fixed the above issue.

Answer (score 0):

it Means that your're tryng to call a method from FRONT END TO BACK END with the WRONG HTTP VERBS (so for example PUT INSTEAD of POST)

double check it

Comment: I am doing a get operation in both end. i am unable to read the custom header in chrome. but in IE it works fine

Comment: have you tried to use OWIN CORS PACKAGE FOR WEBAPI and do app.UseCors(CORS.AllowAll)

Comment: yes i tried with that but not working.  app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);

Comment: can you post your StartUp file (qhere you put the allowcors ) and webconfig?

Comment: startup file : [link](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5hK9Sh)
config: [link](https://dotnetfiddle.net/85CpbC)

Comment: as i immagine ... the line  app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll); ... MUST GO BEFORE EVERYTHING .. so put it in top